# Van Emde Boas Cluster recursion

Tags: algorithms, python

I have been trying to implement a Van Emde Boas tree in python, but I'm having trouble understanding how exactly it works. In the notes [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2012/recitations/MIT6.046J_S12_rec09.pdf), It states that the summary of a VEB structure is another VEB structure, and the individual clusters are also VEB structures. Does that mean that the individual clusters than also contain smaller individual clusters that are VEB structures and so on as well? This is my code to implement the clusters.

```
class VanEmdeBoas():
def __init__(self, size):
    if size <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Invalid size of universe!')
    self.size = 4
    while size > self.size:
        self.size = self.size * self.size
    self.min = None
    self.max = None
    self.clusters = [VanEmdeBoas(math.sqrt(self.size)) for i in range (int(math.sqrt(self.size)))]
```

Doing this results in the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded". Intuitively this fails because the recursion never stops, so does this mean my understanding is flawed?

Comment: You have a bug in your code - your tree has no leaves. Try visualizing what your code is trying to construct, and you'll see that you get an infinite tree. There needs to be a special base case when the number of elements is small.

Comment: So I should make a new class, "VEBLeaf", that is created when the size is 2, as that is the smallest integer square root of the size of the universe?

Comment: How you implement your solution in a program is off-topic here. What is important is to include a base case so that you don't get infinite recursion like you have currently.

Comment: So the leaf would have the exact same properties as  VEB, except it would not have any clusters or summaries, right?

Comment: That's up to you.